# How to sort alphabetically part of the HTML page (images and text)

Tags: javascript, html, alphabetical

I need to order each of the items in the gallery by alphabetical order. Each item would have an image and title.

[image: Screenshot of the working code]

The code for the gallery:

```
<section id="content">
<div class="main">
   <div class="container_24">
       <div class="padding-1">
          <div class="wrapper">
              <article class="grid_24">
                  <h4 class="prev-indent-bot">Piante da interno</h4>
                           <div class="wrapper">
                               <div class="col-3 spacing-3">
                                    <div class="border">
                                        <a class="lightbox-image" href="images/Interno/Phalaenopsis_big.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto[gallery2]"><img src="images/Interno/Phalaenopsis_small.jpg" width="224" height="208" alt=""></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="bg-title">
                                        <div class="box-padding1">
                                            <h5>Phalaenopsis</h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                               <div class="col-3 spacing-3">
                                    <div class="border">
                                        <a class="lightbox-image" href="images/Interno/Capelvenere_big.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto[gallery2]"><img src="images/Interno/Capelvenere_small.jpg" width="224" height="208" alt=""></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="bg-title">
                                        <div class="box-padding1">
                                            <h5>Capelvenere</h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                               <div class="col-3 spacing-3">
                                    <div class="border">
                                        <a class="lightbox-image" href="images/Interno/Kalanchoe_big.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto[gallery2]"><img src="images/Interno/Kalanchoe_small.jpg" width="224" height="208" alt=""></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="bg-title">
                                        <div class="box-padding1">
                                            <h5>Kalanchoe</h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                               <div class="col-3">
                                    <div class="border">
                                        <a class="lightbox-image" href="images/Interno/Nertera_big.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto[gallery2]"><img src="images/Interno/Nertera_small.jpg" width="224" height="208" alt=""></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="bg-title">
                                        <div class="box-padding1">
                                            <h5>Nertera</h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Is there a simple solution using javascript or html?

P.S. sorry for my english.

Comment: this can't be done using html unless its going to be static... then you can just cut and paste the items around to get the correct alphabetical sort. If you want to do this in javascript, you'd have to use jQuery and have each of the div have unique class and then do a sort through that. Can you clarify if this sort have to be dynamic or static?

Comment: How is the html generated? As lifejuggler mentioned, you can just edit the html yourself for a static page. If it is generated using server-side code, I suggest sorting on the server.

Comment: Hi, che code is partial because I have around 50+ images on the page and if I would to add an image I need to add it as html code but then I see the images in sequence al written on the code. I don't want to create a php page or a mysql file to create a database. Let me know if you can help me!  Many thanks.

Comment: The full page online is this: [link](http://www.ortoflorpasino.it/Piante_interno.html)

Comment: @Po1s0n, I'm happy you got help, but note that your original question is significantly different from what you've actually asked to be done in the end. You asked how to sort four items in a contained set of data, but what you really wanted was for someone to sort 50+ items in a page that had somewhat significantly different HTML.

The idea here is not to get someone to build your page for you 100%, but to help you _understand how to solve your problem_. Ultimately you're going to take this code and copy/paste it, but did you learn how to do it next time?

Comment: yes I understand, my question was different from the real online page. Thanks again for your help, but If i need other help with code I need to contact someone because I don't know anything about coding; I had to purchase a template and modify it all without having any basis in html. That's why I've asked help to someone ;) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version that I've tested on the site you've linked:

```
var articles = $('article.grid_24');
articles.each((art_idx, el)=>{
    var art = $(el);
    var boxes = art.find('.wrapper .col-3'); //Get the boxes that have the image and name

    boxes.removeClass('spacing-3'); //Trim out this, since we don't know if any given box will have this after resorting
    boxes.detach(); //Remove the entries without losing their JS attributes
    boxes.sort((a,b)=>{return ($(b).find('h5').text() < $(a).find('h5').text())?1:-1;}); //Sort by the name in the h5 title

    var wrappers = art.find('.wrapper'); //Get the rows
    var wrapper_idx = -1; //At the very first element, this will be incremented to index 0
    boxes.each((idx, box)=>{ //For each content box
        if(idx % 4 === 0) wrapper_idx++; //For each fourth content box, move to the next row
        if((idx+1) % 4) $(box).addClass('spacing-3'); //If it's not the fourth box, give it back this class
        $(box).appendTo($(wrappers[wrapper_idx])); //Add the content box into the current row
    });
});
```

Edit: I have changed this to keep the different elements sorted only between their respective `article` parents.

This can be inserted as a Javascript block after all of the images have loaded. I do agree with Josh Miller in that, ideally, this sorting would actually be done *before* rendering the content, but the above code should work if the content is already displayed.

Comment: But there is another page with more section of images and if I copy the same code at the end of the images I see all the images mixed (but perfectly ordered). [link](http://www.ortoflorpasino.it/Ortaggi.html)

Comment: @Po1s0n That should not be hard to overcome. You can do this process for each article. I'm working on editing my answer to account for that.

Comment: Excuse me for asking, but how do I give an ID to each section? Thanks

Comment: @Po1s0n Simply by adding the HTML attribute `id` to each `article` element (e.g. The article for "Lattughe" would be `<article id="lattughe" class="grid_24"> ... </article>`. However, I'm working on a solution change that would not even require that.

Comment: @Po1s0n I have modified my answer to sort within individual articles. The addition of IDs is not necessary. The new code works on both the previous link you gave, as well as the one with multiple articles that you just gave.

Comment: oh WOW It works perfectly! now my parent's business website will be very well ordered. MANY THANKS FOR YOUR TIME!!!! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following after your HTML (assumes you have jQuery, which it appears you do in your new link):

```
  <script>
  // Create a sorting function
  function sortem(a, b){
    var aName = a.title.toLowerCase();
    var bName = b.title.toLowerCase();
    return ((aName < bName) ? -1 : ((aName > bName) ? 1 : 0));
  }

  // Perform content sort
  function sortContent() {
    var divArr = $(".wrapper.p4 > .col-3")
    var content = [];

    // Clear your content
    $('.wrapper.p4').remove();

    // Put content into an easily managed array
    divArr.each(function(idx,el){
      content.push({
        title: $(el).find('h5').text(),
        html: $(el)
      });
    });

    // Call the sorting function
    content.sort(sortem);

    // Re-render the content
    grid = $("<div></div>");
    for(var i=0;i<content.length;i++){

      if((i+1)%4===0){
        h = content[i].html.removeClass('spacing-3');
      }else{
        h = content[i].html.addClass('spacing-3');
      }

      if(i%4===0){
        grid.append("<div class='wrapper p4'></div>");
      }
      grid.find(".wrapper.p4").last().append(h);
    }

    $('.wrapper article.grid_24 .box-2').after(grid);
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    sortContent();
  });
  </script>
```

I would like to add that this isn't a problem that is ideally solved by JavaScript, but rather by your database query (assuming there is one). Rather than sorting on the client-side, it would make more sense to sort during the database request to eliminate the overhead of re-ordering on the front-end.

```
SELECT title, image
FROM product_table
ORDER BY title ASC
```

That would be far more effective than sorting with JavaScript - particularly given that the value you want to sort by is deeply nested in the HTML.

Comment: @Po1s0n well, what's on the new link that you shared is very different from the snippet in your original question. Instead of just having the four items you need sorted, you have 50+ items that are in repeating sections like you've posted above. I'll try to modify my answer to match the link you provided, but note that the HTML is different from what you've posted here.

Comment: the code is the same, I've only deleted the other images from the code. I've tried your code on the 4 only images page and it does not work.

Comment: @Po1s0n I rewrote the solution given the new requirements and newly provided link. This is a terrible use of JavaScript and _should_ be handled at the database level instead, but this should at least get the result that you asked for.

Comment: Still work but there are some problems, every row of images ( 4 images at the same line) are listed with class wrapper p4 but the last row need to be listed as wrapper. The images with your code looks ordered (the wrapper image at the last row is excluded) and I see all the images duplicated. See the screenshot: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nixbfcw5ebt3hmy/screen.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: @Harris Weinstein managed to put everything in alphabetical order, well done! but there is a problem with the same code on the other pages of gallery.